# Zend_Test - Setting redirect in Controller Plugin for PHPUnit

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, phpunit

I have been trying to use PHPUnit to test an application. I have it all working, but cannot test redirects.

My redirects are occurring inside an Acl Controller Plugin, not inside an Action in a Controller.

I have changed them to use the suggested format of

```
$r = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
$r->gotoSimple("index", "index", "default");
```

But this fails in the tests, the response body is empty and I get errors like

```
Zend_Dom_Exception: Cannot query; no document registered
```

If I then change the test so that the dispatch method does not result in `gotoSimple()` being called then the test runs correctly.

How am I supposed to do a redirect in my application so that it runs correctly with `Zend_Test`'s response object?

The Zend docs cover this in about two lines, which I have tried and it fails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test that redirect has occurred, you need to add

```
$this->assertRedirectTo( 'index' );
```

after running `$this->dispatch();`

You cannot query the response body, since it's empty in case of redirect (that's where your exception comes from).
You can always check what the response actually looks like with

```
print_r( $this->getResponse() );
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Wish I had known that before - so the test does not follow the redirect?

Comment: It doesn't overwrite the response object with the content obtained from redirect - if it's what you mean

Comment: Right - now I know that I can get on. Something that the docs fail to mention!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure, your actions return anything after redirections, because [Zend_Test_PHPUnit disables redirects](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.phpunit.html), so the code after redirect is executed as well.

```
$r = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
$r->gotoSimple("index", "index", "default");
return;
```

or

```
$r = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
return $r->gotoSimple("index", "index", "default");
```

To test the redirect itself, you may use `assertRedirect*` assertions.

Read the above manual, because there are important notes about action hooks.

Comment: I always return after any type of redirect, I think my issue stems from the fact I thought that the test would return the content of the redirect. Now I know it doesn't well is well.